# How to jailbreak 2nd gen iPod Touch without losing data?

Tags: ipod-touch, backup, jailbreak, restore

I have an 8GB iPod Touch 2nd Generation that runs iOS 4.2.1, and currently it is not jailbroken.

I want to jailbreak it using redsn0w version 0.9.6b4. I have found [these](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=12953) instructions, but I will lose data if I follow them. I have backed my data up using iTunes. How can I jailbreak it without losing my data? Or can I restore the backed up data without removing the jailbreak?

Comment: Jailbreaking doesn't erase any of your data.

Comment: My experience is the steps listed by abdullah kahraman are wrong. Don't use redsnOw.

Comment: @MorganMcGahan If they were wrong, I would lose my data, which I didn't. Maybe you have done something wrong..

Answer (score 2):

I've used redsn0w on iPod touch 2nd Gen. You will not lose any data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using greenpois0n. Go to http://greenpois0n.com/downloads/ and follow the instructions. I have jailbroken my iPod and did not lose any data.